# How can I instruct AutoFixture to not bother filling out some properties?

Tags: c#, .net, autofixture

I have a set of Data Access classes that are nested fairly deep.

To construct a list of 5 of them takes AutoFixture more than 2 minutes.  2 minutes per Unit test is way to long.

If I was coding them by hand, I would only code up the ones I need, so it would initialize quicker. Is there a way to tell AutoFixture to only do some of the properties so it can not spend time with areas of my structure I don't need?

For example:

```
public class OfficeBuilding
{
   public List<Office> Offices {get; set;}
}

public class Office
{
   public List<PhoneBook> YellowPages {get; set;}
   public List<PhoneBook> WhitePages {get; set;}
}

public class PhoneBook
{
    public List<Person> AllContacts {get; set;}
    public List<Person> LocalContacts {get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set;}
   public string LastName { get; set;}
   public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
   public char Gender { get; set; }
   public List<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
}

public class Addresses
{
   public string Address1 { get; set; }
   public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Is there a way to tell AutoFixture to create values for `OfficeBuilding.Offices.YellowPages.LocalContacts`, but not to bother with `OfficeBuilding.Offices.YellowPages.AllContacts`?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One option is to create a Customization that omits properties of a certain name:

```
internal class PropertyNameOmitter : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> names;

    internal PropertyNameOmitter(params string[] names)
    {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var propInfo = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo != null && names.Contains(propInfo.Name))
            return new OmitSpecimen();

        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}
```

You may use it as below:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customizations.Add(
    new PropertyNameOmitter("AllContacts"));

var sut = fixture.Create<OfficeBuilding>();
// -> The 'AllContacts' property should be omitted now.
```

---

See also:

- [Omit properties by type](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/69#issuecomment-12991183)
- [Omit properties by namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17301813/467754)

Comment: Nowadays `return new NoSpecimen(request);` (obsolete) could be replaced with `return new NoSpecimen();`

Answer (score 56):

The answer provided by Nikos Baxevanis provides various convention-based ways to answer the question. For completeness sake, you can also do a more ad-hoc build:

```
var phoneBook = fixture.Build<PhoneBook>().Without(p => p.AllContacts).Create();
```

If you want your Fixture instance to always do this, you can Customize it:

```
fixture.Customize<PhoneBook>(c => c.Without(p => p.AllContacts));
```

Every time that Fixture instance creates an instance of PhoneBook, it'll skip the AllContacts property, which means that you can go:

```
var sut = fixture.Create<OfficeBuilding>();
```

and the AllContacts property will remain untouched.