# How can I use custom ISpecimenBuilders with OmitOnRecursionBehavior?

Tags: autofixture

How can I use custom `ISpecimenBuilder` instances along with the `OmitOnRecursionBehavior` which I want applied globally to all fixture-created objects?

I'm working with an EF Code First model with a foul-smelling circular reference that, for the purposes of this question, cannot be eliminated:

```cs
public class Parent {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I'm familiar with the technique for side-stepping circular references, as in this passing test:

```cs
[Theory, AutoData]
public void CanCreatePatientGraphWithAutoFixtureManually(Fixture fixture)
{
    //fixture.Customizations.Add(new ParentSpecimenBuilder());
    //fixture.Customizations.Add(new ChildSpecimenBuilder());
    fixture.Behaviors.OfType<ThrowingRecursionBehavior>().ToList()
                     .ForEach(b => fixture.Behaviors.Remove(b));
    fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior());
    fixture.Behaviors.Add(new TracingBehavior());
    var parent = fixture.Create<Parent>();
    parent.Should().NotBeNull();
    parent.Child.Should().NotBeNull();
    parent.Child.Parent.Should().BeNull();
}
```

But if either/both customizations are uncommented, I get an exception:

```cs
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.OmitSpecimen' to type 'CircularReference.Parent'.
```

The failing cast is occurring in my `ISpecimenBuilder` implementations (shown at the bottom of this question) when I call on the `ISpecimenContext` to resolve `Parent` and the request is coming from the `Child` being resolved. I could guard against the request coming from the `Child` resolving operation like this:

```cs
//...
&& propertyInfo.ReflectedType != typeof(Child)
//...
```

But, that seems to pollute the `ISpecimenBuilder` implementation with knowledge of 'who' might be making the request. Also, it seems to duplicate the work that the 'global' `OmitOnRecursionBehavior` is meant to do.

I want to use the `ISpecimenBuilder` instances because I have other things to customize besides handling the circular reference. I've spent a lot of time looking for examples of a scenario like this here on SO and also on [Ploeh](http://blog.ploeh.dk/tags.html#AutoFixture-ref) but I haven't found anything yet that discusses the **combination of behaviors and customizations**.  It's important that the solution be one that I can encapsulate with `ICustomization`, rather than lines and lines in the test setup of

```cs
//...
fixture.ActLikeThis(new SpecialBehavior())
       .WhenGiven(typeof (Parent))
       .AndDoNotEvenThinkAboutBuilding(typeof(Child))
       .UnlessParentIsNull()
//...
```

...because ultimately I want to extend an `[AutoData]` attribute for tests.

What follows are my `ISpecimenBuilder` implementations and the output of the `TracingBehavior` for the failing test:

```cs
public class ChildSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var propertyInfo = request as PropertyInfo;
        return propertyInfo != null
               && propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Child)
                   ? Resolve(context)
                   : new NoSpecimen(request);
    }

    private static object Resolve(ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var child = (Child) context.Resolve(typeof (Child));
        child.Name = context.Resolve(typeof (string)).ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
        child.Age = Math.Min(17, (int) context.Resolve(typeof (int)));
        return child;
    }
}

public class ParentSpecimenBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var propertyInfo = request as PropertyInfo;
        return propertyInfo != null
               && propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof (Parent)
                   ? Resolve(context)
                   : new NoSpecimen(request);
    }

    private static object Resolve(ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var parent = (Parent) context.Resolve(typeof (Parent));
        parent.Name = context.Resolve(typeof (string)).ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
        parent.Age = Math.Max(18, (int) context.Resolve(typeof (int)));
        return parent;
    }
}

CanCreatePatientGraphWithAutoFixtureManually(fixture: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Fixture) : Failed  Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
    Requested: CircularReference.Parent
      Requested: System.String Name
        Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
          Requested: System.String
          Created: 38ab48f4-b071-40f0-b713-ef9d4c825a85
        Created: Name38ab48f4-b071-40f0-b713-ef9d4c825a85
      Created: Name38ab48f4-b071-40f0-b713-ef9d4c825a85
      Requested: Int32 Age
        Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
          Requested: System.Int32
          Created: 9
        Created: 9
      Created: 9
      Requested: CircularReference.Child Child
        Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
          Requested: CircularReference.Child
            Requested: System.String Name
              Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
                Requested: System.String
                Created: 1f5ca160-b211-4f82-871f-11882dbcf00d
              Created: Name1f5ca160-b211-4f82-871f-11882dbcf00d
            Created: Name1f5ca160-b211-4f82-871f-11882dbcf00d
            Requested: Int32 Age
              Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
                Requested: System.Int32
                Created: 120
              Created: 120
            Created: 120
            Requested: CircularReference.Parent Parent
              Requested: CircularReference.Parent
              Created: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.OmitSpecimen

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.OmitSpecimen' to type 'CircularReference.Parent'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it an option to customize the creation algorithm using the `Customize` method?

If yes, you can create and use the following `[ParentChildConventions]` attribute:

```
internal class ParentChildConventionsAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    internal ParentChildConventionsAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new ParentChildCustomization()))
    {
    }
}

internal class ParentChildCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Child>(c => c
            .With(x => x.Name,
                fixture.Create<string>().ToLowerInvariant())
            .With(x => x.Age,
                Math.Min(17, fixture.Create<int>()))
            .Without(x => x.Parent));

        fixture.Customize<Parent>(c => c
            .With(x => x.Name,
                fixture.Create<string>().ToUpperInvariant())
            .With(x => x.Age,
                Math.Min(18, fixture.Create<int>())));
    }
}
```

The original test, using the `[ParentChildConventions]` attribute, passes:

```
[Theory, ParentChildConventions]
public void CanCreatePatientGraphWithAutoFixtureManually(
    Parent parent)
{
    parent.Should().NotBeNull();
    parent.Child.Should().NotBeNull();
    parent.Child.Parent.Should().BeNull();
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I think I was trying to make it too complicated, but I had seen various solutions in which the `ICustomization` implementation would simply add one or more `ISpecimenBuilder` implementations to the fixture's Customizations collection. Am I missing the point about when it's more appropriate to do that vs. your solution?

Comment: Usually you create an `ISpecimenBuilder` for infrastructure purposes (e.g. to [omit properties of a certain  kind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346803/how-can-i-instruct-autofixture-to-not-bother-filling-out-some-properties/18352867#18352867)). To supply specific value(s) to particular member(s) you may start with the `Customize` method and optionally create an `ISpecimenBuilder` along the way.

Comment: Another thing… I notice you've omitted any calls to remove `ThrowingRecursionBehavior` and/or add `OmitOnRecursionBehavior`, and yet the tests still pass. Does the `.Without()` call avoid the detection of this circular reference before `ThrowingRecursionBehavior` gets a chance to throw an exception?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [AutoFixture.AutoEntityFramework](https://github.com/alexfoxgill/AutoFixture.AutoEntityFramework) to help with EF.