# Autofixture configure relationship between parent and child

Tags: parent-child, relationship, autofixture

It seems like I can't find an easy way to create relationship between parent and child using autofixture. Let is say I have a class `Order` and `OrderLine` and `OrderLine` is linked with `Order` by `OrderId`. Now I have a list of `Order`s and I want that each order inside the list have a few `OrderLine` and `OrderLine` should have the same `OrderId` as per the `Order` class.

How to configure this relationship? `fixture.AddManyTo(orderlist)` adds many orders with many `OrderLine`s but they are all random `Id`s and `OrderIds`.

`fixture.Create` or `Customize` doesn't seem to be the right ones??

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Here's a useful [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840537/creating-a-domain-model-without-circular-references-in-entity-framework#comment29586458_19840537), and a related [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18601592/467754) to this question.

Comment: Hi, this looks like an answer though not sure how to mark it as answer

Comment: Sorry this is not a solution for me. I realised AutoDataAttribute is not supported in MSTest so the solution does not really work for me!!

Comment: That's not a problem. Just use the `Fixture` instance directly, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had come across this exact same issue, there is a [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoEF) package which extends fixture for you.  In essence it makes sure that OrderLine.Order.Id == OrderLine.OrderId.

Comment: This seems like what I wanted